# Toggle between asc and desc for datatable column sort

Tags: sorting, datatables

Code bellow is used to sort the column 2 of the table to descending order.

```
tablename.order( [2,'desc'] ).draw();
```

I am using a dropdown to select the column to sort.

Is there any way to toggle between ascending and descending each time i select a column from dropdown?

Comment: I think it is possible. What did you try? Could You please add a jsFiddle to make helping you easier for other stackoverflow users?

Comment: you can get the current order tablename.order() then look at the current direction and reverse it. The method returns the current value if you pass nothing to it. https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()

Comment: @PaulZepernick, Yh that helped ,thanks. Your comment is the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I added it as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current order tablename.order() then look at the current direction and reverse it. The method returns the current value if you pass nothing to it. https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()